# Reinforcement Learning - after 800k timesteps agent wont learng

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I'm study and try a reinforcement learning.
now im using gym and stable-baseline.

My project have a step where I calculate a reward with a function.

> -> step() 
> -> calculate_reward() 
> -> return calculated reward 
>  -> in step():
> I set **total_reward = -1000** and **Done = True**

But agent will interrupt everytime to this step becouse it using the same action.

```
Tick: 23
Price: 131.067600 - Next Price: 126.127800 - Action: 0 - Reward: 4.939800
Tick: 24
Price: 128.367200 - Next Price: 130.804100 - Action: 0 - Reward: -2.436900
Tick: 23
Price: 131.067600 - Next Price: 126.127800 - Action: 0 - Reward: 4.939800
Tick: 24
Price: 128.367200 - Next Price: 130.804100 - Action: 0 - Reward: -2.436900
Tick: 23
Price: 131.067600 - Next Price: 126.127800 - Action: 0 - Reward: 4.939800
Tick: 24
Price: 128.367200 - Next Price: 130.804100 - Action: 0 - Reward: -2.436900
```

What is wrong in my concept?
My notebook colab is: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1HxjONW_QvYPagk7clUrUPFAkpJ59OwZ8?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change some parameters of your A2C model, perhaps the learning rate or the alpha/epsilon/gamma/momentum, for instance:

```
model = A2C('MlpLstmPolicy', env, verbose=1, learning_rate=0.0001, alpha=0.001, momentum = 0.02)
```

or using a different LSTM architecture, for instance:

```
policy_kwargs = dict(net_arch=[64, 'lstm', dict(vf=[128, 128, 128], pi=[64, 64])])
model = A2C('MlpLstmPolicy', env, verbose=1,policy_kwargs = policy_kwargs)
```

I don't know which parameter could be the best, it depends on your data.

Note that stock markets might need data scaling techniques in order to reach better results.

Comment: Thank you. I've added a notebook

Comment: Great. I've answered accordingly.

Comment: Well, now work up to ticker: 27, and the agent use everytime action 1, that is wrong becouse reward is negative. (https://pastebin.com/heciS4ZY)